# useContext values gets cleared during page refresh and logout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

While updating the profile, `profile.name` gets displayed via `useContext()`in navlink (Navigation.js). But as soon as page gets refresh or during logout the profile.name gets cleared, also `profile.photo` is not displaying too in navlink.

I want to display the name and photo always in nav link,  how can i do that. ?

`UserProfileProvider.js`

```
import React, { useMemo, useState} from 'react';
import UserProfileContext from '../context';

const UserProfileProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [profile, setProfile] = useState({ _id: '', photo: '', name: '', email:'', phonenumber:'', position:'', privilege:'', password:''});

    const value = useMemo(() => ({
        profile, setProfile
    }), [profile]);


    return (
       <UserProfileContext.Provider value={value}>
           {children}
       </UserProfileContext.Provider>
    )   
}
export default UserProfileProvider;
```

`Navigation.js`

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { NavLink, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserProfileContext from '../context';


const Navigation = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const {profile} = useContext(UserProfileContext); // added 16 jun based on stack

    const divStyle = {
        float:'left',
        color: '#64cad8', 
        padding: '0px 0px 0px 10px',
        font:'Lucida, sans-serif'
      };

    function logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('loginEmail')
        localStorage.removeItem('Privilege')
        history.push('/login')
        window.location.reload(true);
      }

    return localStorage.getItem('loginEmail') &&
        <div className="App">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div id="wrap">
                    <nav className="siteNavigation_nav_links">
                    <div className="clubLogo landing"style={divStyle}><b>Southside Soccer</b></div>
                        <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/profile">Profile</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="mobile_login_link" to="/login" onClick={logout}>Logout</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="mobile_login_link" to='/aboutus'>About us</NavLink>
                        <span className="mobile_login_link">{profile.name}<img className="nav_profile"src={profile.photo}></img></span>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}

export default Navigation;
```

`App.js`

```
import UserProfileProvider from './components/UserProfileProvider.js';

var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

const App = () => {                       // added 16 jun based on stack

  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <UserProfileProvider>
          <>
        <Navigation />
          <Switch>
              <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/aboutus" component={Aboutus} />
              <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route exact path="*" component={ErrorPage} />
          </Switch>
          </>
      </UserProfileProvider>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App, null),
  document.getElementById("root")
);

export default App;
```

`Profile.js`

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import UserProfileContext from '../context';

const {profile, setProfile} = useContext(UserProfileContext);
...// rest of the Profile component code...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. Because react is client-side, so whenever you refresh data was lost (contextAPI or any state management). You can use `useEffect` or `componentDidMount` lifecycle to fetch data user again every mount `App` component

Comment: Ok, Where should i use again the `useEffect()` again.? Should I use that in Navigation.js ?

Comment: Also may I also know why the `profile.photo` is not there ?

Comment: For global state, fetch user data on Root component to assurance data always available before render child component

Comment: remind that all the state will be lost whenever you refresh

Comment: Do you mean to use `useEffect()` on root component ie, `UserProfileProvider.js`  ?

Comment: place on inside App.js